# Docker updating image along when dockerfile changes

Tags: docker

I'm playing with docker by creating a `Dockerfile` with some nodejs instructions. Right now, every time I make changes to the dockerfile I recreate the image by running `sudo docker build -t nodejstest .` in my project folder however, this creates a new image each time and swallows my ssd pretty soon.

Is there a way I can update an existing image when I change the dockerfile or I'm forced to create a new one each time I make changes to the file?

Sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: Not a dumb question at all.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Docker build support caching as long as there is no `ADD` instruction. If you are actively developing and changing files, only what is after the `ADD` will be rebuilt.

Since 0.6.2 (scheduled today), you can do `docker build --rm .` and it will remove the temporary containers. It will keep the images though.

In order to remove the orphan images, you can check them out with `docker images`, and perform a `docker rmi <id>` on one of them. As of now, there is an auto-prune and all untagged images (orphans, previous builds) will be removed.

Comment: Warning: '-rm' is deprecated, it will be replaced by '--rm' soon.

Comment: This answer should probably be updated with `--rm`; it's still one of the top answers for a "docker update image" google search.

Comment: @branch14 When I go `docker build --rm` I get *"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument* and then, the computer tells me to seek help.

Comment: @KonradViltersten `docker build` takes exactly one (positional) arg which is a path. It's usually where your Dockerfile is located. Flags like `--rm` are not counted as args.

Answer (score 20):

According to this [best practices guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20200415055839/http://crosbymichael.com/dockerfile-best-practices.html) if you keep the first lines of your dockerfile the same it'll also cache them and reuse the same images for future builds

Comment: That's something I love about Docker!

Comment: Is this still valid? The best practices link is not.

Answer (score 1):

During development, it makes less sense to re-build a whole container for every commit. Later, you can automate building a Docker container with your latest code as part of your QA/deployment process.

Basically, you can choose to make a minimal container that pulls in code (using git when starting the container, or using `-v /home/myuser/mynode:/home/myuser/mynode` with ENTRYPOINT to run node).

See my answer to this question:

[Docker rails app and git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806179/docker-rails-app-and-git/18816278#18816278)