# Docker php url access

Tags: php, docker

I've build [my php images with Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and running it with :

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name r-lafermeduweb lafermeduweb`

But i can't access to my app.
I've test my 192.168.10.xx:8080, and not found.

I've try with :

`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 0005086cf69c // return 172.17.0.2`

But `172.17.0.2:8080` not exist too.

Do you have any idea why i can access to my php app ?

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

Thank you !

Comment: I think you have left something out of your post because I can't understand what is going on.

Comment: The 172 address is the Docker container's internal IP address. The web site will be available at the computer's IP address if the ports have been properly exposed during your build. We'd have to see your Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi guys, i've edit my first post with my Dockerfile :) Thank you !

Comment: YOu have binded it to your localhost
so http://localhost:8080/ should work, otherwise your service on 8080 port did not start

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your desired port(eg: 8000) to 80 port of the container.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name r-lafermeduweb lafermeduweb
```

Comment: its exposed by default via the base dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

If you refer here the base docker file being users port 80 is exposed [by default](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/76a1c5ca161f1ed6aafb2c2d26f83ec17360bc68/7.0/apache/Dockerfile) so technically this should work when you hit localhost or your host ip address.

Maybe you forgot to re-build the image before running, everytime you change the dockerfile you need to build a fresh image and run that.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804124/docker-updating-image-along-when-dockerfile-changes) for more information